# CIRCUITPYTHON drive not showing on rear USB ports

Tags: pi-pico, adafruit, circuitpython

So I have a Raspberry Pi Pico running circuitpython and other prerequisites for the pico rgb keypad, and as shown in the title above, for some reason the circuit python drive only shows and the program  loaded on it only runs when plugged in the front side usb ports of my computer. It works in BOOTSEL mode in the back and front USBs as well, just not in CIRCUITPYTHON. I'm doing this with the same cable as well, and I know USB devices like drives and keyboards work in those USB ports. Also I'm using a Corsair 5000D ATX mid case and an PRO Z690-A WIFI DDR4(MS-7D25) on ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Does anyone know why this might be happening, and a solution to make it work in the back USB ports? It seems no one else is having this problem online, and I'm wondering if its a driver or hardware issue.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I just recently found out that the pico works as it should when the computer is in BIOS mode - I can't tell if the drive is there or not but the script loaded on it starts, unlike when I'm using it normally. I also just tested it on windows similarly and it doesn't show up there either, on the same computer

Comment: your title is unclear ... what back USB ports are you asking about?

Comment: back USB ports as in their position on the computer - most have some on the front and then some on the back